# Deletion in Binary Search Tree in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

i am constructing the operations of `binary search tree` in OCaml.

```
type ('a, 'b) bst = 
  | Node of 'a * 'b * ('a, 'b) bst * ('a, 'b) bst
  | Leaf;;

let rec insert k v = function
  | Leaf -> Node (k, v, Leaf, Leaf)
  | Node (k', v', left, right) ->
    if k < k' then Node (k', v', insert k v left, right)
    else if k = k' then Node (k, v, left, right)
    else Node (k', v', left, insert k v right);;

let rec delete k = function
  | Leaf -> Leaf
  | Node (k', v, l, r) as p ->
    if k < k' then Node (k', v, (delete k l),r)
    else if k > k' then Node (k', v, l, (delete k r))
    else 
    match (l, r) with
      | (Leaf, Leaf) -> Leaf
      | (l, Leaf) -> l
      | (Leaf, r) -> r
      | (_, _) ->
        let Node (km, vm, _, _) = max l in
        Node (km, vm, delete km l, Leaf)
```

**Can anyone tell me whether my `deletion` code is good enough or any improvement?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One improvement is the case when we insert things that are in the tree, or delete things that are not in the tree. Each of these operations will duplicate the search path to that particular node. Insertion is probably not a problem since you will want to update the value of that key, but deletion would be a case where you can make an improvement. This can be solved by wrapping the function with an exception to return the original tree.

Here is what a deletion would look like for something that is not in the tree. As you recurse you create a new `Node` with the key deleted in the correct subtree. In this particular case the delete function will recurse to a `Leaf` then return a `Leaf` and on each step back up the stack return a newly constructed `Node`. This new path is represented as the blue path below. Since there is no structure to unwind the new path to the old path we re-create the search path in the result tree.

```
let at = delete x bt
```

[image: non-existent deletion]

To fix this issue, as mentioned wrap the function in an exception.

```
let delete k t =
    let rec delete k = function
        | Leaf -> raise Not_found
        ...
    in
    try delete k t with Not_found -> t
```

Comment: I think in my case, if deletion can't find the key, then the same tree will be returned, isn't it?

Comment: No. I describe the deletion correctly above. It is the same tree structurally, but not physically. Those recursive calls re-construct a new `Node` each call. You can think of it as preparing a new node in the assumption that we are going to delete something on the left subtree (or right). Of course that assumption is not true, and we end up at a `Leaf`, which returns a `Leaf` but in no way unwinds the new path to the old one when nothing is deleted.

Comment: It's just a performance improvement that would only come into play on large trees or where the data on the tree is large. In general though, I think it's a good illustrative example of properly dealing with recursive data-structures and how they are stored in memory at a high-level. Okasaki mentions it in exercise 2.3 in his book, "Purely Functional Data Structures".